# Drivers for HP Ink Tank 415 for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers

Please help finding drivers for HP Ink Tank 415 for Ubuntu 16.04. I used HP guide but it does not work.

Comment: Please edit the question to include a link to the "hp guide" you used. And please explain exactly what leads you to believe that it didn't work. Exact error messages, if any, are very helpful.

Comment: What is "hp ink tank 415"? Do you use this name for some InkJet printer? What is exact device model?

Comment: hi, exact name  of a printer is hp ink tank wirless 415, and I  used driver from https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing, but then some error ocurs it sais: "there was a problem opening a file...hplip- 3.18.12.run and I do not know what to do then

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have an HP Ink Tank Wireless 415 printer and are running this under Ubuntu Linux.  If this is the case, then you should find the driver you require using the following link to HP Developers Portal, home of HP's Linux Imaging and Printing software (HPLIP):

https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing

Comment: I  used driver from https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing, but then some error ocurs it sais: "there was a problem opening a file...hplip- 3.18.12.run and I do not know what to do then